# Footer row using CSS-Grid won't stick to bottom in mobile-device view

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using HTML and CSS (Grid) to make a fairly simple website. There is 1 column and 5 rows for the main grid. In the 4th row there is a grid with 1 row and 3 columns.

Everything works fine except when I toggle the Device Toolbar in Chrome's Developer tools. The footer is moved up and is covering the 4th row that has a grid within it.

That 4th row with a grid within it is set to change using a `@media` screen tag. It changes to 1 column with 4 rows when the screen is less than 840px.

The main wrapper code:

```
.wrapper {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  -ms-grid-rows: 5% 15% 20% 60% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 5% 15% 20% 60% 30%;

  height: 100vh;
}
```

The 4th row within the main wrapper with a grid in it:

```
@media (max-width: 840px) {
  .main_services_wrap {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    -ms-grid-rows: 5% 100% 100% 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 5% 100% 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worded this answer terribly. To re-iterate my problem, I had a 5th row acting as a footer using CSS Grid. Whenever content in the main row (the 4th row) exceeded its height, the content would expand beneath the footer row, and the footer row stayed in place.

My issue was that I gave the 4th row, the main content, a specified height. So when content in the 4th row exceeded that height, it expanded past the 5th row, the footer. I set the 4th row to a height of `auto` in the stylesheet and now the 4th row expands with the content and forces the 5th row, the footer, to remain at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: red;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: yellow;
}


@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}

body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
  </article>
  <footer class="footer">row1</footer>
  <footer class="footer">row2</footer>
  <footer class="footer">row3</footer>
  <footer class="footer">row4</footer>
  <footer class="footer">row5</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```